# Transforming an Array into a new structure

Tags: php, arrays

I have this current structure:

```
{"resultset":[
{"IM":[2],"SR":[2],"TA":[4],"PMT":[2],"IMT":[2]},
{"IM":[1],"SR":[0],"TA":[4],"PMT":[1],"IMT":[0]},
{"IM":[2],"SR":[5],"TA":[17],"PMT":[2],"IMT":[5]}
]
}
```

I need to generate a foreach loop (I think) searching an each key and transforming the structure to look like this instead:

```
{"resultset":[  {"IM":[2,1,2],"SR":[2,0,5],"TA":[4,4,17],"PMT":[2,1,2],"IMT":[2,0,5]} ]}
```

I know I have to use a foreach loop and search on the key and then push the data back into a new array with this structure. but im having difficulty getting my head around it. any help would be appreciated.

I might need to change my strategy here:

this is my current code that is generated the first array:

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($teams);$i++)
  { 
   $openResultSet['resultset'][]  = $DAL->runGenericSQL(TotalTicketsInQueue($teams[$i]),"open",$i);
  }
```

this calls the following (in a nutshell)

```
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($resultSet))
{
    $OpenTicketResultArray["IM"][] = intval($row["IM"]);
    $OpenTicketResultArray["SR"][] = intval($row["SR"]);
    $OpenTicketResultArray["TA"][] = intval($row["TA"]);
    $OpenTicketResultArray["PMT"][] = intval($row["IM"]);
    $OpenTicketResultArray["IMT"][] = intval($row["SR"]);   
}
return $OpenTicketResultArray;
```

I'm thinking at each iteration when the first array comes back store the results in a new key'd array and then continue to push the new results. but I'm new to this :(

Comment: Looks like a case for array_merge_recursive()

Comment: are you sure `PHP` `arrays`?

Comment: Something like `$data = call_user_func_array(
    'array_merge_recursive', 
    array_map(
        function($value) { 
            return (array) $value; 
        }, 
        $data->resultset
    )
);
echo json_encode($data);
` will come pretty close

Comment: Hi Damon.s, sorry the array structure above is in the JSON format that is sent back to the client. essentially I need the second JSON format to work with my highchart solution